# Perl non-greedy matching

Tags: regex, perl

Consider this non-greedy matching; given:

```
my $seq = "TTATGCTTCTTATGCCCACACACACCCACTCACCCATT";
```

I want to match `TTATGCCCACACACACCCACTCACCCATT` non-greedily.

I tried the following:

```
($match) = $seq =~ m/(TTATG.*?CCATT)/;
($match) = $seq =~ m/(TTATG(.*)?CCATT)/;
($match) = $seq =~ m/(TTATG.+?CCATT)/;
```

But $match is always assigned to the entire string, i.e.

```
TTATGCTTCTTATGCCCACACACACCCACTCACCCATT
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's because $hit is assigned the first capture variable, which matches everything. What are you trying to match ?

Comment: Why not just search for the string you are looking for `TTATGCCCACACACACCCACTCACCCATT`? or is part of that string dynamic? You could do `.*(TTAT.*)`, if you want the last occurrence of `TTAT` then everything else.

Comment: And the reason it matches everything is there is only one substring `CCATT` so greedy or not it matches everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frugal (aka non-greedy or lazy) means "shortest", but still "leftmost". You need look-around assertions to find the other matches:

```
 while ($seq =~ m/(?=(TTATG.*?CCATT))/g) {
    say for $seq, $1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.+?` matched `GCTTCTTATGCCCACACACACCCACTCACC` because `GCTTCTTATGCCCACACACACCCACTCACC` is the least `.+?` can match at position 5 (where `TTATG` left off) and still allow the rest of the pattern to match.

---

You want one of the following, probably the last one:

```
/ ( TTATG (?:(?!TTATG).)* CCATT ) /xs
/ ( TTATG (?:(?!CCATT).)* CCATT ) /xs
/ ( TTATG (?:(?!TTATG|CCATT).)* CCATT ) /xs
```

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `[^CHAR]*` as `(?:STRING)` is to `CHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

To get to the inner `TTATG` there are a few ways.

One is `^.*(TTATG.+?CCATT)`, which goes to the end, will get the *last*.

Another is `(TTATG(?:(?!TTATG).)*?CCATT)` which will find an un-nested pair.

In your case, both match the same thing.

(*If for any reason you think overlapping matches will actually help you here

I'd say it's probably the wrong assumption.*)